# Why does reducing the load impedance _increase_ the voltage drop, but reducing the source impedance _reduce_ the voltage drop?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics

When the input impedance is small, we get a large input current and large voltage drop.

When the output impedance is small, we get a large output current, small voltage drop.

Both are resistors and use the same formula (V=IR). Why is the voltage drop different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will become clear when you realize that the source and load resistance form a 2-resistor voltage divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f08XoF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- In the first case, the load resistance is the bottom resistor.
- In the second case, the source resistance is the top resistor.

That's why they have opposite effects:

- Decreasing the load resistance decreases the voltage across it, resulting in a larger voltage drop (from the voltage source's voltage).
- Decreasing the source resistance decreases the voltage across it, resulting in a smaller voltage drop (from the voltage source's voltage).